# How to create multidimensial arrays with PHP and access with jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have got to a stage in my website where I need to pack a lot of information into a single json array like object, so in order to do this I need to pack a list of array information under a certain key name, then another set of data under another key name.

So for example:

```
$array = array();

foreach(action goes here)
{
    $array['data1'] = array('information' => data, 'more_information' => more_data)
}

$array['data2'] = array("more data");
```

This basically illustrates what I am trying to do, I am able to partially do this, however naming the key for the new data set only replaces each data, instead of adding into it in the foreach loops.

Now if this part isn't too confusing, I need some help with this. Then in addition to this, once this is sorted out, I need to be able to use the data in my jQuery response, so I need to be able to access each set of data something like: json.data1[i++].data, which would ideally return "more_information".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an incremental number in that loop and make the results available as a json object...

```
$array = array();
$i = 0;

foreach(action goes here)
{
    $array['data'.$i] = array('information' => data, 'more_information' => more_data)
    $i++;
}

$array['data2'] = array("more data"); 

$data = json_encode($array);
```

Then in php you might set a js var like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;
</script>
```

which could then be accessed in js easily:

```
alert(data.data1.information);
```

If I understand your question correctly you expect to get this object as a response to something? Like a jQuery .ajax call?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

This link illustrates how to use it pretty clearly. You would want to make sure to specify `dataType = "json"` and then place your data handling in the success call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'some url string',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(i, v){
            console.log(data[i]);
        });
    },
    error: function()
    {
        //error handling
    }
});
```

This is relatively untested, but the concept is what I am trying to convey. You basically make your multi-dimensional array in php and json_encode it. Either of these methods will allow you to parse the json.

Comment: Thanks for your time for helping me out with this, however I don't think a crucial part of my question was quite clear enough (or maybe it was), but I'll just try to explain it to make sure. I want to have three sub arrays, with keys something like: "add", "remove", "update", then the values of each of those would be an array of data, this would be so I can add the certain data that is passed back to javascript, or remove the data passed back, or update the data passed back, depending on what the user does to the files. then in the ajax success I sort of need to be able to use $.each() on....

Comment: each of the sub arrays of data, for example: $.each(data.add), $.each(data.remove), $.each(data.update), and then it would go through the arrays of those keys.

Comment: You are in full control of what you json encode. There's nothing saying you can't json encode array('add' => array(), 'remove' => array(), 'update' => array()) and access it just as you mentioned here. what have you tried and what results did you get?

Comment: The example I gave in my question is nearly what I have tried. (As far as creating the arrays), the problem I have had has been that when I create the key how I did, it will only allow for one loop of data to be stored, as it replaces it, instead of adding it to the arrays.

Comment: After waking up and re reading your comment, I realized what you meant, and now I believe I have figured out what I needed to do. Thanks.